# Relative path to log4j.xml in Spring MVC Project using Tomcat

Tags: spring-mvc, log4j

Im trying to configure log4j with a relative path to put the .log-Files to. Files are correctly getting generated when I specify a absolute path but are not generated AT ALL when i use something else. I tried  the following

- {CATALINA_HOME}
- ./filepath
- ${webapp.root} And setting the listeners and all that stuff, as described here [HowTo configure....](http://www.megadix.it/content/how-configure-relative-paths-log4j-using-spring)

I am working on a Mac with the Spring Source Tools and the project I created with the Spring Source Tools put the log4j.xml into src/main/resources and NOT into the WEB-INF folder as stated in most of the tutorials. I tried variant 3 (webapp.root...) and it actually finds the log4j.xml where I declare it (I put it into WEB-INF and it works) but still no logging to a file when I use ${webapp.root}.

How do you solve that problem? This is horrible, I cant push this stuff to our repo with an absolute path to my user-dir??

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In appenders in src/main/resources/log4j.xml 
we use

```
 <param name="file" value="${catalina.home}/logs/catalina.out"/>
```

Also check permissions? - hope that helps

Comment: which permissions do you mean?

Comment: Ok it worked, I think it was really just my mistake that I used _ instead of . Thank you Shaun! To everybody else: Maybe its worth trying to use catalina.base instead of catalina.home. I read that it behaves different, depending on the environment...